# Looping gsub() replacing elements from a list of multiple words into a corpus

Tags: r, loops, gsub

I have a corpus of 233 documents (**ecb_corpus**) and a list of multiwords (**ecb_final**). I want to replace every brigram and trigram in my multiwords list into my corpus.

This is my multiwords list:

```
1   euro_area
2   monetary_policy
3   price_stability
4   interest_rates
5   second_question
6   medium_term
7   first_question
8   central_banks
9   inflation_expectations
10  structural_reforms
```

I just managed to do it for one single case by using ***gsub***:

```
ecb_ready <- gsub(pattern = "interest rate", replacement= "interest_rates", ecb_corpus, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, fixed = TRUE)
```

To get the results I want, in *pattern* there should be any word of the corpus (**ecb_corpus**) and in *replacement* my list of multiwords (**ecb_final**). I have been trying completely unsuccessfully loops (quite new to R and not able yet to do them unfortunately).

Is there anyone who can help me loop it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do clearly. Can you make this short and complete by including a compete example along with expected output ?

Comment: @RonakShah please look at the answer below given by DHW. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringr::str_replace_all()` can do this directly. That's what the help file is trying to ever-so-briefly communicate with "Vectorised over `string`, `pattern` and `replacement`."

Here I assume that your corpus is stored in a character vector, but it could be a list of characters, as well. If it's more complicated (e.g. it's in JSON...) then you might need to do some preprocessing before you feed it to `str_replace_all()`.

Note that the result drops the names of the input elements, but it'd be easy to restore them.

```r
library(tidyverse)

(ecb_corpus <- c(
  doc_1 = c("lorem ipsum interest rate gobbledygook"),
  doc_2 = c("lorem dolor central bank foobar")
))
#>                                    doc_1 
#> "lorem ipsum interest rate gobbledygook" 
#>                                    doc_2 
#>        "lorem dolor central bank foobar"

replacements <- c("euro_area",
                  "monetary_policy",
                  "price_stability",
                  "interest_rates",
                  "second_question",
                  "medium_term",
                  "first_question",
                  "central_banks",
                  "inflation_expectations",
                  "structural_reforms")

targets <- replacements %>% str_replace_all("_", " ") %>% str_remove("s$")

(replacement_pairs <- replacements %>% set_names(targets))
#>                euro area          monetary policy          price stability 
#>              "euro_area"        "monetary_policy"        "price_stability" 
#>            interest rate          second question              medium term 
#>         "interest_rates"        "second_question"            "medium_term" 
#>           first question             central bank    inflation expectation 
#>         "first_question"          "central_banks" "inflation_expectations" 
#>        structural reform 
#>     "structural_reforms"

(ecb_ready <- ecb_corpus %>% str_replace_all(replacement_pairs))
#> [1] "lorem ipsum interest_rates gobbledygook"
#> [2] "lorem dolor central_banks foobar"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>